# Foreign Key não respeita integridade referencial

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Estou tentando unir tabelas e adicionar uma `chave estrangeira`, para que por exemplo, uma tabela de compras tenha `referência` da `id` da tabela de compradores.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
alter table compras add foreign key (compradores_id) references compradores(id);
insert into compras (valor, recebido, data, compradores_id) values (1500, 1, '2016-06-02', 15);
```

*As `id's` da tabela compradores só vão até `3`
*Ambas as colunas (`compradores.id e compras.compradores_id`) foram configuradas como `int not null`

Ele aceita o comando de `insert` numa boa e grava, como posso corrigir isso ?

Comment: Você poderia postar os campos e o tipo de cada campo destas duas tabelas?

Comment: O engine da sua tabela é innodb ou mysam?

Comment: É preciso ter constraint, tem que ser do tipo igual, integer (11), integer (11), unsignet, not null e por aí vai...

Comment: @rray, como verifico isso ?

Comment: @Gumball, eu setei ambas do mesmo jeito :/ por isso não entendo o pq de estar bugando

Comment: Na criação da tabela no final tem essa informação.

Comment: @rray, ambas são MyISAM

Comment: Tenta colocar InnoDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A integridade referencial no MySQL funciona somente quando as tabelas usam o engine innoDB. O primeiro passo é mudar o tipo das tabelas e depois aplicar a foreign key, uma vez que os valores devem obedecer as restrição.

```
ALTER TABLE nome_da_tabela ENGINE=INNODB
```

[MySQL - innoDB documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: muito obrigado, assim que alterei pra INNODB rodou liso :D

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) o comando correto seria o seguinte:

```
ALTER TABLE compras
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_compras_compradores_20161215
FOREIGN KEY (compradores_id)
REFERENCES compradores(id)
```

Também é importante verificar se `compradores_id` é do mesmo tipo que o `id` do comprador.

Comment: Eu posso estar enganado, mas acho que W3Scholls não tem nada a ver com W3C.

Comment: Opa, perdão rsrsrsr. Fazendo mil coisas aqui rsrsrsr

Comment: Continua inserindo, mesmo com a adição de `constraint`

Comment: Se puder postar a estrutura das tabelas, vai ajudar a elucidar um pouco mais