# Método rollback não funciona em classe estendida da mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, innodb

Olá,
por conta da versão do PHP no servidor, os métodos fetch all e begin_transaction do mysqli não funciona. Para resolver isso, criei outra classe de conexão estendendo a classe MySQLi e passei a instanciá-la.

```
<?php
namespace App\DB;

class MySQLiConnector extends \mysqli
{
    function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db)
    {
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    }

    public function query($query) {
        if( !$this->real_query($query) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return new MySQLiResultSet($this);
    }

    public function begin_transaction($flags = NULL, $name = NULL)
    {
        $this->autocommit(FALSE);
    }
}
```

e a classe mysqliresultset

```
<?php
namespace App\DB;

class MySQLiResultSet extends \MySQLi_Result
{
    public function fetch()
    {
        return $this->fetch_assoc();
    }

    public function fetch_all()
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $this->fetch())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}

?>
```

Porém, quando eu tento usar o método mysqli->rollback() quando determinada query falha, o mesmo não funciona, as alterações são salvas mesmo assim.

O código onde eu tento executar o rollback:

```
        $this->db->begin_transaction();

        $query1 = $this->db->query($sql1);
        $query2 = $this->db->query($sql2);
        $query3 = $this->db->query($sql3);


        if (!$query1 || !$query2 || !$query3) {
           $this->db->rollback();
           throw new ModelException("Erro da base de dados. -> ".$this->db->error);
        } else {
           $this->db->commit();
           return true;
        }
```

Existe alguma forma de resolver este problema?

Comment: Você sobrescreveu o método original `begin_transaction()` do MySQLi, pode ser que vc não tenha nem iniciado a trasanção, por isso talvez as alteração sejam efetuadas.

Comment: O método original begin_transaction() só está disponível a partir do php 5.5, no servidor roda o 5.3, por isso o refiz :x.

Comment: Não tinha essa informação na pergunta mas tudo bem, verifique se conexão passada (onde vc aplica o autocommit false) é a mesma que recupera a consulta (`MySQLiResultSet`) parece que o objeto q vc aplica o autocommit é diferente do que executa/recupera a consulta.

Comment: Perdão, eu já arrumei a pergunta. Vou verificar isso que você falou.

Comment: Tem outro detalhe importante suas tabelas usam o engine InnoDB?

Comment: Putz, eu jurava que usavam... mas não, usam MySAM. É isso, pois testei em outra base com tabelas innodb e funcionou. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This function doesn't work with non transactional table types (like MyISAM or ISAM).

Conforme o [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php) alerta. Apenas tabelas com o engine InnoDB ou NDB suportam transações logo `autocommit(FALSE)` não vai funcionar com tabelas MyIsam. No site do MySQL existe uma [lista comparativa](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html) das funcionalidades de cada engine.

Outra funcionalidade que o InnoDB possui e o MyIsam é a opção de chaves estrangeiras com integridade referencia.

**Relacionada:**

[Foreign Key não respeita integridade referencial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171644/91)