# Problema relacionamento chave estrangeira no PhpMyAdmin - Wamp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, chave-estrangeira, wampserver

Estou com 'problema' no meu Wamp, mais precisamente na última versão (Wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit x64).

Quando crio 2 tabelas, exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE categoria(
    id_categoria INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_categoria)
);


CREATE TABLE chamado(
    id_chamado INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_categoria INT NOT NULL,
    titulo VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_chamado),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_categoria) REFERENCES categoria(id_categoria)
);
```

Executo e crio as tabelas, porém, o PhpMyAdmin não cria o relacionamento de forma automática entre a chave estrangeira com a chave primária da outra tabela, coisas que, com o XAMP funcionam automaticamente.

Preciso que seja criado automaticamente o relacionamento entre as tabelas, até para que eu consiga utilizar o Mysql com o Hibernete (acontece com o Hibernete também).

Penso que possa ser alguma configuração, alguém saberia como resolver?

Obrigado desde já.

-----------> Atualização:

Tabela Categoria: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela Chamado: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Insert na tabela Chamado através do PHPMyAdmin:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por mais que a tabela categoria tenha registros, posso adicionar qualquer id na chave estrangeira da tabela chamado que não ocorre nenhum erro. Coisas que, utilizando o Xamp, funciona, o qual relaciona as duas tabelas e abre uma opção com o id da chave estrangeira na hora do insert.

Comment: Verifique se o problema que está tendo não é [Storage Engine](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171644/foreign-key-n%C3%A3o-respeita-integridade-referencial/171653#171653)

Comment: Mesmo especificando as chaves estrangeiras, posso fazer inserts sem referenciar, exclusões, e nada retorna erro.

Comment: @AgnaldoJunior, você tentou fazer como o DNick, disse, seria algo como `ALTER TABLE nome_da_tabela ENGINE=INNODB`, ou no phpMyadmin em Operations > table options, e alterar o Storage Engine

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, porém não resolveu. Atualizei a postagem adicionando mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

> Uma chave estrangeira (FK) é uma coluna ou combinação de colunas usada para estabelecer e impor um link entre os dados de duas tabelas, a fim de controlar os dados que podem ser armazenados na tabela de chave estrangeira. Em uma referência de chave estrangeira, cria-se um link entre duas tabelas quando a coluna ou as colunas que contêm o valor de chave primária para uma tabela são referenciadas pela coluna ou colunas de outra tabela. Essa coluna torna-se uma chave estrangeira na segunda tabela.

Sendo assim, ela pode ser nula, ou ter um valor não referenciado na outra tabela. Não necessariamente precisa existir nas duas tabelas.

Pelas fotos a chave estrangeira está funcionando. Faça uma consulta que utilize dados das duas tabelas para testar sua funcionalidade.

Teste:

```
Select ca.nome, ch.titulo from categoria as ca, chamado as ch where ch.id_categoria = ca.id_categoria
```