# Foreign key não funciona! MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde galera, alguém poderia me ajudar? Minha foreign key não está funcionando em um database.
Eu já tinha feito uma foreign key em outro database do mesmo jeito, só que agora não está funcionando sem motivo aparente.
Já mudei a engine pra INNODB, já tentei um alter table, mas nada...

Segue as tabelas:

```
**Tabela cargos:**

create table cargos

(

cod_cargo int auto_increment primary key,

nome_cargo varchar(45)

)

**Tabela funcionarios:**

create table Funcionarios 

(

cracha int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 

nome varchar(50), 

sobrenome varchar(50), 

email varchar(50), 

senha varchar(20), 

cpf varchar(14), 

data_de_nascimento varchar(10),

sexo char(1),

cidade varchar(35),

tel_fixo char(13),

tel_movel char(14),

foto varchar(50),

cargo_funcionario int,

salario decimal (8,2),

observacoes text,

foreign key (cargo_funcionario) references cargos(cod_cargo)

)
```

Comment: O engine da sua tabela é MyIsam ou InnoDB? [Foreign Key não respeita integridade referencial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/171653/91)

Comment: A engine é InnoDB

Comment: QUando vc diz não funciona o que exatamente acontece, é um erro? tem a mensagem? se não poderia descrever com mais detalhes.

Comment: Por "não está funcionando " devemos entender ...

Comment: testei aqui e foi tranquilo.

Comment: Tenho 20 linhas inseridas na tabela cargos, porém, quando tento inserir um valor maior que 20 no campo cargo_funcionario da tabela funcionarios ele não retorna erro e insere normalmente, ou seja, quando eu insiro um novo funcionario com uma id de cargo maior do que o permitido ele executa tranquilamente, o que não era pra acontecer.

Comment: Faz um `show create table Funcionarios` veja se realmente o engine é innodb, só para confirmar.

Comment: É sim, acabei de executar o comando e no final apareceu "ENGINE=InnoDB"